# NativeScript TNS App_Resources for Android

Tags: nativescript

I am using Nativescript's TNS tool to create application. But when I see App_resources section for android it is different from sample Groceries app. Adding images below. Is there something else I need to do with TNS tool to match the same folder structure?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Because all resources in app_resource/Android/* will be copied to android platform. So, the structures should be the same as android resource directory structure, you can reference [Providing Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

As matter of fact, my resource directory structure is the same your last image; and it run fine (accept for values directory, I haven't try it yet).

Comment: Can u please read my question again. My question was why tns tool is not generating same folder structure that android needs.